# Permanently NOT index certain folders

Tags: intellij-idea

A lot of my projects contain `tmp` folders. I always have to exclude them (and, sometimes it seems like IntelliJ forgets these exclusions).

Is there a way to permanently, for all time, make IntelliJ ignore a folder named `tmp` for all projects, new and old?

Comment: Currently it's not possible. Feel free to vote for the related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150784